# Ticks disappears under the axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

Knows someone why in this draw the ticks doesn't appears under the axis?

```
\newcommand{\myaxis}[1]{
    \draw[->] (0,#1) -- (25,#1);
    \foreach \x in {0,...,24} {
        \draw (\x,#1)++(0,3pt) -- (\x,#1)++(0,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm]

% By default, tikz uses centimeters (cm) as unit

    \myaxis{1}
    \foreach \x in {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24} {
        \draw[red,fill=red] (\x,1) circle (5pt);
    }

    \myaxis{0}
    \foreach \x in {3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24} {
        \draw[red,fill=red] (\x,0) circle (5pt);
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what do you mean by `under`?

Comment: `\draw (\x,#1)++(0,-3pt) -- (\x,#1)++(0,-3pt)` instead of `\draw (\x,#1)++(0,+3pt) -- (\x,#1)++(0,-3pt)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean like on image below:

[image]

or

[image]

in this case you should replace

```
\newcommand{\myaxis}[1]{
    \draw[->] (0,#1) -- (25,#1);
    \foreach \x in {0,...,24} {
        \draw (\x,#1)++(0,3pt) -- (\x,#1)++(0,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
    }
}
```

with

```
\newcommand{\myaxis}[1]{
    \draw[->] (0,#1) -- ++(25,0);
    \foreach \x in {0,...,24} {
        \draw (\x,#1) -- ++(0,-4pt) node[below] {$\x$};
    }
}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\myaxis}[1]{
    \draw[->] (0,#1) -- ++(25,0);
    \foreach \x in {0,...,24} {
        \draw (\x,#1) ++(0,3pt) -- ++(0,-6pt) node[below] {$\x$};
    }
}
```

Comand `\draw (\x,#1)++(0,3pt) -- (\x,#1)++(0,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};` means, that line is drawn between `(\x,#1)++(0,3pt)` and `(\x,#1)`. Node is further moved from your axis for `(0,-3pt)`. Complete MWE for second case:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myaxis}[1]{
\newcommand{\myaxis}[1]{
\draw[->] (0,#1) -- ++(25,0);
\foreach \x in {0,...,24} {
    \draw (\x,#1) ++(0,3pt) -- ++(0,-6pt) node[below] {$\x$};}
                   }  
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm]
% By default, tikz uses centimeters (cm) as unit
    \myaxis{1}
    \foreach \x in {2,4,...,24} {
        \draw[red,fill=red] (\x,1) circle (5pt);
    }
    \myaxis{0}
    \foreach \x in {3,6,...,24} {
        \draw[red,fill=red] (\x,0) circle (5pt);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution solved the issue, thanks. (I like tex by their results, but its syntax could be really maddening)